# excel datasource returning nulls with sql command

Tags: excel, ssis, integration, vba

I'm reading excel sheet that has a column formated as number but every now and then contains letters. These are returned as NULLS. I need the values. I added IMEX=1 and that did not help. Changing Values in the registry is not an option. the columns are fixed so is there a way to manually set them to string?

I also tried changing it from advance editor and they go back to the default that is double float.

I am getting the data with an SQL command. Is there a way to force the column to be a type with cast or convert from here? I tried with cast and I keep getting an error.

Comment: Everytime I've set the datatype in the advanced editor, it always works for me.   Can't imagine why it's not working for you.

Comment: I've done it before and it worked fine but in the scenario it keeps changing back no matter what I change it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that cast and convert does not work in this context. I used CSTR(). I was getting error displaying this cell in the preview but the end product was good.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading in the columns as varchar, then either use a data conversion or derived column transformation within the SSIS package, or update the data once read into the db using cast or convert.

Comment: I use a connection string for my excel source so every time a new file comes in it re-checks the columns and then decides to put it as double float. If I could just read it I can convert to the correct types after but everything I try I get nulls where it's alphabetical.